# AWS PostgreSQL RDS: more than 10GB increase in Freeable Storage Space without any data removed

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, storage, rds

While monitoring the metrics of my Amazon PostgreSQL RDS (db.t2.small) I noticed sudden increases in the amount of Free Storage Space. This looks rather worry some because it would imply that more 10 GB of space was removed. While checking up on the data, everything was still in place.

Has anyone encountered this before and can explain why it happens?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a 'autovacuum' feature that is used to reclaim unused space.

All AWS RDS Postgres instances now have this featured enabled by default, so if all your data is still there, there is a good chance this is what led to more free space for you:

> The autovacuum feature for PostgreSQL databases is a feature that we
>   strongly recommend you use to maintain the health of your PostgreSQL
>   DB instance. Autovacuum automates the execution of the VACUUM and
>   ANALYZE command; using autovacuum is required by PostgreSQL, not
>   imposed by Amazon RDS, and its use is critical to good performance.
>   **The feature is enabled by default for all new Amazon RDS PostgreSQL** **DB**
>   **instances**, and the related configuration parameters are appropriately
>   set by default.

More about PostGres autovacuum:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/routine-vacuuming.html

Comment: Thanks! It indeed turn out to be the autovaccuum function. By running "SELECT * FROM pg_stat_all_tables" I could identify that some tables were autovaccuumed.

Comment: `VACUUM` reclaims disk space in very specific conditions only. If the conditions are not met, the space is marked as `free`, and Postgres can reuse it, but it is not given back to the OS